# Not able to fix file handling issue in python

Tags: python

I wrote python code to search a pattern in a tcl file and replace it with a string, it prints the output but the same is not saved in the tcl file

```
import re
import fileinput
filename=open("Fdrc.tcl","r+")
for i in filename:
    if i.find("set qa_label")!=-1:
        print(i)
        a=re.sub(r'REL.*','harsh',i)
        print(a)
filename.close()
```

**actual result**

> set qa_label
>   REL_ts07n0g42p22sadsl01msaA04_2018-09-11-11-01
>
> set qa_label                                   harsh

Expected result is that in my file it should reflect the same  result as above but it is not

Comment: This is the second problem I've seen today that asks how to "change" the content of a file. Generally you don't. You either read all the data into the memory, modify it, and write it back to the same file; or you first write the results into a separate file, then rename it to overwrite the original.

Comment: Where is the logic that is supposed to be saving a modified version of your file?  You're not writing to the file at all in this code.

Comment: I wonder if there is an answered duplicate question that I can point people to.

Comment: hi this searches a pattern in file and prints on the shell and changes the substring but it doesn't  actually change in the file i need to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually write your changes back to disk if you want to see them affected there.  As @ImperishableNight says, you don't want to do this by trying to write to a file you're also reading from...you want to write to a new file.  Here's an expanded version of your code that does that:

```
import re
import fileinput
fin=open("/tmp/Fdrc.tcl")
fout=open("/tmp/FdrcNew.tcl", "w")
for i in fin:
    if i.find("set qa_label")!=-1:
        print(i)
        a=re.sub(r'REL.*','harsh',i)
        print(a)
        fout.write(a)
    else:
        fout.write(i)
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

Input and output file contents:

```
> cat /tmp/Fdrc.tcl
set qa_label REL_ts07n0g42p22sadsl01msaA04_2018-09-11-11-01

> cat /tmp/FdrcNew.tcl
set qa_label harsh
```

If you wanted to overwrite the original file, then you would want to read the entire file into memory and close the input file stream, then open the file again for writing, and write modified content to the same file.

Here's a cleaner version of your code that does this...produces an in memory result and then writes that out using a new file handle.  I am still writing to a different file here because that's usually what you want to do at least while you're testing your code.  You can simply change the name of the second file to match the first and this code will overwrite the original file with the modified content:

```
import re

lines = []

with open("/tmp/Fdrc.tcl") as fin:
    for i in fin:
        if i.find("set qa_label")!=-1:
            print(i)
            i=re.sub(r'REL.*','harsh',i)
            print(i)
        lines.append(i)

with open("/tmp/FdrcNew.tcl", "w") as fout:
    fout.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: hi  i need to change in the original file  this creates a new file but i have to use original file it wont help please suggest code to do changes in original file

Answer (score 0):

Open a tempfile for writing the updated file contents and open the file for writing.

After modifying the lines, write it back in the file.

```py
import re
import fileinput
from tempfile import TemporaryFile


with TemporaryFile() as t:
    with open("Fdrc.tcl", "r") as file_reader:
        for line in file_reader:
            if line.find("set qa_label") != -1:
                t.write(
                str.encode(
                    re.sub(r'REL.*', 'harsh', str(line))
                    )
                )
            else:
                t.write(str.encode(line))
        t.seek(0)

    with open("Fdrc.tcl", "wb") as file_writer:
        file_writer.writelines(t)
```

Comment: Does this really work?  Did you test it?  I've never seen two file handles opened on the same file at the same time.  But I guess since only one is opening the file for writing, it could potentially be OK.  However, why add this complexity?  Your solution doesn't rely on both the `file_reader` and `file_writer` being available at the same time.  Why not open the file for writing after having closed it for reading as my solution does?  Also, why impose the extra disk IO involved in writing to a temporary file, just to turn around and write the result into another file?

Comment: It doesn't really work when run entirely. I updated to fix that. While writing this answer, I  tested in a repl. "Why not open the file for writing after having closed it for reading as your solution does?" That is the correct way to handle it. "why impose the extra disk IO involved in writing to a temporary file" I agree with that memory is cheaper in most cases. I'm not sure what the results are for a lot more data in the memory.